# Airflow: How to only send email alerts when it is not a consecutive failure?

Tags: airflow

I've an airflow dag that executes 10 tasks (exporting different data from the same source) in parallel, every 15min. I've also enabled 'email_on_failure' to get notified on failures.

Once every month or so, the tasks start failing for a couple of hours due to the data source not being available. Causing airflow to generate hundreds of emails (10 emails every 15min.), until the raw data source is available again.

Is there a better way to avoid being spammed with emails once consecutive runs fail to succeed?
For example, is it possible to only send an email on failure once it is the first run that start failing (i.e. previous run was successful)?

Answer (score 3):

To customise the logic in callbacks you can use `on_failure_callback` and define a python function to call on failure/success. in this function you can access the [task instance](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/taskinstance/index.html#airflow.models.taskinstance.TaskInstance).

A property on this task instance is `try_number` - which you can check before sending an alert. An example could be:

```py
some_operator = BashOperator(
    task_id="some_operator",
    bash_command="""
        echo "something"
    """,
    on_failure_callback=task_fail_email_alert,
    dag=dag,


def task_fail_email_alert(context):
    try_number = context["ti"].try_number
    if try_number == 1:
        # send alert
    else:
        # do nothing
```

You can them implement the code to send an email in this function, rather than use the builtin `email_on_failure`. The `EmailOperator` is available by importing `from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator`.

Comment: Is this also possible for consecutive runs? This determines the try number of the current run (i.e. a retry of the same run), correct? Therefore I'll still receive an email each each 15 min. if the pipeline keeps failing.

Comment: This gives you the try number of the current task instance in the dag run. If you had 10 instances of this dag running concurrently, you would receive 10 emails if this task failed across all 10. Then any retries of this task would not send an alert. Do you want to alert if the task fails, or if the dag run itself fails?

Answer (score 1):

Giving consideration that your tasks are running concurrently and one or multiple failures could occur, I would suggest to treat the dispatch of failure messages as one would a shared resource.

You need to implement a lock that is "dagrun-aware" –– one that knows about the DagRun.

You can back this lock using an in-memory database like Redis, an object store like S3, system file, or a database. How you choose to implement this up to you.

In your `on_failure_callback` implementation, you must acquire said Lock. If acquisition of said `Lock` is successful, carry on to dispatch the email. Otherwise, pass.

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook


class OnlyOnceLock:

    def __init__(self, run_id):
        self.run_id = run_id

    def acquire(self):
        # Returns False if run_id already exists in a backing store.
        # S3 example
        hook = S3Hook()
        key = self.run_id
        bucket_name = 'coordinated-email-alerts'
        try:
            hook.head_object(key, bucket_name)
            return False
        except:
            # This is the first time lock is acquired
            hook.load_string('fakie', key, bucket_name)
            return True

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.acquire()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):  
        pass
```

```py
def on_failure_callback(context):
    error = context['exception']
    task = context['task']
    run_id = context['run_id']
    ti = context['ti']
    with OnlyOnceLock(run_id) as lock:
        if lock:
            ti.email_alert(error, task)
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, this makes sure only a single email is send per executed run (instead of 10 in my example), correct? 
How about also determining if the previous run was failing, would that also be possible? Such that once a DAG is failing, I'm not receiving an email each 15 min.

Comment: To do that, I believe you'd have check the state of the previous DAG from the metastore.